# Excel Find and Replace Formula

Tags: excel

In column A I have a name…..Joe Smith
In column B I have a bunch of words and the word *REPLACE*
I need column C to contain everything in column B, but I need the word “REPLACE” from column B to be replaced with the name from Column A.

Original Column B: Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Description -like "*REPLACE*"'-Property Name,Description | Select -Property Name,Description

Column C should say: Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Description -like "*Joe Smith*"'-Property Name,Description | Select -Property Name,Description

Side note: I tried to use the Find and Replace function in Excel, but I do not know how to add a column letter to replace the find with, which is why I am asking for help.

Comment: You have stated what you *need* but not asked a question nor shown your attempt to resolve this.

Comment: I tried to use the Find and Replace function in Excel, but I do not know how to add a column letter to replace the find with, which is why I am asking for help.

Comment: If you want the results in column C then you could use a formula to replace the text and copy this formula down the column. Which Excel function(s) can perform the replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **C1** enter:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(B1,"REPLACE",A1)
```

[image]

Comment: This was it! Thank you!